# WebSphere deployment ClassCastException: PrivateOptions incompatible

Tags: ant, build, websphere

I am trying to build my source code and getting the below error. I am using an Ant script and trying to create a build for WebSphere Application Server 8.5.

```
[exec] Error executing deployment: java.lang.ClassCastException. Error is com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.batch.impl.PrivateOptions incompatible with com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.batch.impl.PrivateOptions.
[exec] java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.batch.impl.PrivateOptions incompatible with com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.batch.impl.PrivateOptions
[exec]  at com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.batch.plugin.BatchExtension.run(BatchExtension.java:246)
[exec]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[exec]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
[exec]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
[exec]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
[exec]  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(EclipseAppContainer.java:587)
[exec]  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:198)
[exec]  at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
[exec]  at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
[exec]  at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
[exec]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[exec]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
[exec]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
[exec]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
[exec]  at com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.batch.impl.BootLoaderLoader.run(BootLoaderLoader.java:494)
[exec]  at com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.batch.impl.BatchDeploy.execute(BatchDeploy.java:114)
[exec]  at com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.EJBDeploy.execute(EJBDeploy.java:106)
[exec]  at com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.EJBDeploy.deploy(EJBDeploy.java:348)
[exec]  at com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.EJBDeploy.main(EJBDeploy.java:309)
[exec] EJBDeploy level: @build@
```

Comment: Can you show your Ant script?  Are you using the `ant` command from a local Ant install or the `WAS_HOME/bin/ws_ant.bat` (or `.sh`) command?

Comment: Thanks for reply Brett.

Comment: I have shared file at link   http://www.filedropper.com/wsant.Please down load the file from this link

Comment: Is this is the ws_ant.bat from WAS_HOME/bin or have you made modifications?  If it's from WAS_HOME/bin, then this looks like a product issue, so I would recommend opening a PMR with IBM.

Comment: I am also sharing my ejbdeply.bat file  at link http://www.filedropper.com/ejbdeploy

Comment: No this file I have taken from sever and have not done any  modification.

Comment: Please explain opening PMR with IBM ,I am not aware of this.

Comment: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21507639